# Flask WTForms - how to skip validation on fields in invisible div?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I have created a WTform in Python Flask, where I have a delivery form. If customer's billing address is different from delivery address then i am enabling div which contains fields for billing address. I am doing hiding and showing of div via jquery.
Originally i had all the fields in one Flaskform, but then i thought if i put billing fields in separate FlaskForm, and handle form.validate_on_submit() separately for 2nd form then may be i can skip validation for fields in Billing div.
But no, it is still performing validation on those fields, and because of that I am not able to move forward. If user has same addresses then billing fields will be empty and can't pass validation.
I am sure people must have encountered this situation but i can't find any answer regarding this.
Could someone guide me?

I am attaching code, to explain myself.

My Forms.py

```
class DeliveryForm(FlaskForm):

    choices_billadd = [('1', 'Use delivery address'), ('2', 'Add a billing address')]

    addressline1 = StringField('Address Line 1*',
                           validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=100)])
    addressline2 = StringField('Address Line 2',
                           validators=[Length(max=100)])
    city = StringField('City*',
                           validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=50)])
    postcode = StringField('Postcode*',
                           validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=50)])

    billingaddress = SelectField('Billing Address*', choices = choices_billadd, validators = [DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

class BillingForm(FlaskForm):
    bill_addressline1 = StringField('Address Line 1*',
                           validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=100)])
    bill_addressline2 = StringField('Address Line 2',
                           validators=[Length(max=100)])
    bill_city = StringField('City*',
                           validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=50)])
    bill_postcode = StringField('Postcode*',
                           validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=50)])
```

```
<form method="POST" action="">
                {{ form.csrf_token(id='login_csrf') }}
                <fieldset class="form-group content-section">

                    <div class="row pt-3">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            {{ form.addressline1.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                            {% if form.addressline1.errors %}
                                {{ form.addressline1(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    {% for error in form.addressline1.errors %}
                                        <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            {% else %}     
                                {{ form.addressline1(class="form-control") }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            {{ form.addressline2.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                            {% if form.addressline2.errors %}
                                {{ form.addressline2(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    {% for error in form.addressline2.errors %}
                                        <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            {% else %}     
                                {{ form.addressline2(class="form-control") }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row pt-3">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            {{ form.city.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                            {% if form.city.errors %}
                                {{ form.city(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    {% for error in form.city.errors %}
                                        <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            {% else %}     
                                {{ form.city(class="form-control") }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            {{ form.postcode.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                            {% if form.postcode.errors %}
                                {{ form.postcode(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    {% for error in form.postcode.errors %}
                                        <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            {% else %}     
                                {{ form.postcode(class="form-control") }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row pt-3">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            {{ form.billingaddress.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                            {{ form.billingaddress(class="form-control") }}
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div id="div_billingaddress" class="">
                        <div class="row pt-3">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                {{ form_bill.bill_addressline1.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                                {% if form_bill.bill_addressline1.errors %}
                                    {{ form_bill.bill_addressline1(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {% for error in form_bill.bill_addressline1.errors %}
                                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </div>
                                {% else %}     
                                    {{ form_bill.bill_addressline1(class="form-control") }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                {{ form_bill.bill_addressline2.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                                {% if form_bill.bill_addressline2.errors %}
                                    {{ form_bill.bill_addressline2(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {% for error in form_bill.bill_addressline2.errors %}
                                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </div>
                                {% else %}     
                                    {{ form_bill.bill_addressline2(class="form-control") }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row pt-3">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                {{ form_bill.bill_city.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                                {% if form_bill.bill_city.errors %}
                                    {{ form_bill.bill_city(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {% for error in form_bill.bill_city.errors %}
                                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </div>
                                {% else %}     
                                    {{ form_bill.bill_city(class="form-control") }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                {{ form_bill.bill_postcode.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                                {% if form_bill.bill_postcode.errors %}
                                    {{ form_bill.bill_postcode(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {% for error in form_bill.bill_postcode.errors %}
                                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </div>
                                {% else %}     
                                    {{ form_bill.bill_postcode(class="form-control") }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="row py-4">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-success btn-block") }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: if the forms are two, you will need to define the two forms separately ie `delivery_form =  DeliveryForm(request.form)` and same for the billing form so that when you are validating you do something like `if delivery_form.validate_on_submit():` I am supposing you know how to check the form in the request so that you know which one to validate

Comment: @MosesN.Njenga I am already defining two separate forms as you mentioned, and validating separately. Could you please advise how to check the form in request. Currently, I have dropdown which enable and disables one form div. So i was checking the value of that to handle validating form. But still validation is being done on both. Also, validation fails before even hitting ```if delivery_form.validate_on_submit()```. Does validation happens because form was initialised in GET request. ```if form.billingaddress.data == '2':
                if form_bill.validate_on_submit():```